# Factory method on base class to instantiate derived classes

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to have a generic factory method on my base class that can instantiate any of the descendant classes, without the base class knowing what all the descendants are. The following produces working JS, but...

- Despite having the `///<reference>` I get a TS warning (see code): Property 'Base' does not exist on type 'typeof MyNS'
- There are ample [warnings in the Typescript docs about wrapping modules in namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#do-not-use-namespaces-in-modules).
- This approach only appears to work if the files are concatenated into a single outFile given the way the classes are bound to `exports` (see gist at bottom). That could be acceptable, but I'm curious if there is a way that doesn't have this limitation.

*Base.ts:*

```
export namespace MyNS {
    export abstract class Base {
        static create(foo) {
            return new MyNS[foo.type]();
        }
    }
}
```

*Descendant.ts:*

```
/// <reference path="Base.ts" />
export namespace MyNS {
    // Property 'Base' does not exist on type 'typeof MyNS':
    export class Descendant extends MyNS.Base {
        echo(s: string) {
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting JS: https://gist.github.com/zbjornson/2053cf1a30e893f38f7910dcada712d2

What's a better way to expose the descendant classes to the base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posting one answer I came up with, but still very welcoming of any other solutions.)

One way is with decorators:

*Base.ts*:

```
var descendants = {};
export abstract class Base {
    static create(foo) {
        return new descendants[foo.type](foo);
    }

    static Descendant(constructor: Function) {
        descendants[constructor.name] = constructor;
    }
}
```

*Descendant.ts*:

```
import { Base } from "./Base.ts";

@Base.Descendant
export class Descendant extends Base {
    echo(s: string) {
        return s;
    }
}
```